# How to trigger to send an email via a link

Tags: jquery, email, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I hope to have a link in my Jquery Mobile page, when the user click on that link, he can send an email to me, with the sendto and subject filled in.

I hope that they can launch the email app no matter in Android or iOS.

Is it possible? If not,through a web email page is still ok to me.

Thank you!

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">contact me</li>
            <li><a href="A_URL_TO_SEND_EMAIL">email us    : xxxxxxx@gmail.com</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of use, but it's a horrible hack and you should not expect it to work, or keep working in the future.

```
<a href="mailto:foobar@example.com?subject=Hell+world&body=argle+bargle">click here</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome! But why it is a hack? Would you also please explain how this works? Is it working for native app or web app? Is it some features for jquery mobile or html5 or something? Would you please explain for a little bit?

Comment: `mailto` tells the browser to fire up the system's default mail client, and the query parameters can be used to fill in stuff in the email. It's a hack in that it was never part of any standard, and there's no guarantee that any particular browser will support it, or support it in the future.

Comment: So, there is no good way to achieve something like this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="mailto:emailname@yourdomain.com?subject=subject">link</a>
```

Doesn't work in everything